# HighCharts - Filling a heatmap from SQL Query

Tags: json, highcharts

Im trying to fill a [HighCharts Heatmap](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/heatmap/) with data returned from an SQL Query.

What i have in the JS file is

```
    $(function () {
  var chart;
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $.getJSON("php/all-counties-sales-data-box.php", function(json) {


    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

      chart: {
          renderTo: 'chart-box-combined',
          type: 'heatmap',
          marginTop: 40,
          marginBottom: 80,
          plotBorderWidth: 1
      },


      title: {
          text: 'Sales per employee per weekday'
      },

      xAxis: {
          categories: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
      },

      yAxis: {
          categories: ['Lucozade', 'Rockstar', 'Sprite', 'Monster', '7Up', 'Fanta', 'Coke'],
          title: null
      },

      colorAxis: {
          min: 0,
          minColor: '#FFFFFF',
          maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
      },

      legend: {
          align: 'right',
          layout: 'vertical',
          margin: 0,
          verticalAlign: 'top',
          y: 25,
          symbolHeight: 280
      },

      tooltip: {
          formatter: function () {
              return '<b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + '</b> sold <br><b>' +
                  this.point.value + '</b> items on <br><b>' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '</b>';
          }
      },

      series: [{
          name: 'Sales per Shell',
          borderWidth: 1,
          data:
          [[0, 0, 10], [0, 1, 19], [0, 2, 8], [0, 3, 24], [0, 4, 67], [0, 5, 67], [0, 6, 67],
          [1, 0, 92], [1, 1, 58], [1, 2, 78], [1, 3, 117], [1, 4, 48], [1, 5, 48], [1, 6, 48],
          [2, 0, 35], [2, 1, 15], [2, 2, 123], [2, 3, 64], [2, 4, 52],
          [3, 0, 72], [3, 1, 132], [3, 2, 114], [3, 3, 19], [3, 4, 16],
          [4, 0, 38], [4, 1, 5], [4, 2, 8], [4, 3, 117], [4, 4, 115],
          [5, 0, 88], [5, 1, 32], [5, 2, 12], [5, 3, 6], [5, 4, 120],
          [6, 0, 13], [6, 1, 44], [6, 2, 88], [6, 3, 98], [6, 4, 96],
          [7, 0, 31], [7, 1, 1], [7, 2, 82], [7, 3, 32], [7, 4, 30],
          [8, 0, 85], [8, 1, 97], [8, 2, 123], [8, 3, 64], [8, 4, 84],
          [9, 0, 47], [9, 1, 114], [9, 2, 31], [9, 3, 48], [9, 4, 91],
          [10, 0, 47],
          [11, 0, 47],

        ],

          dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              color: '#000000'
          }
      }]
    });
});

});

});
```

And what im trying to fill it with is data from the query

```
    $sth = mysql_query("Select SUM(Profit) as profitSum From FactSales GROUP BY ShellType, SaleMonth");
$rows1 = array();
$rows1['profit'] = 'profitSum';
while($rr = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows1['series'][] = $rr['profitSum'];
}

$result = array();
array_push($result,$rows1);
```

What do i actually need to change for the "series" data to be filled with the data returned from the sql query?

Heres the JSON response as requested

```
[{"profit":"profitSum","data":[1329230,1796743,1789417,1327813,1457103,1198845,1859826,1770589,1555410,1310369,2183499,1212897,6424306,6426002,6345153,6167415,6969392,5974880,6407699,6278843,6622002,5962102,5198177,5386392,72991,2321397,1751565,2029890,642041,1314314,1322492,1557859,1647784,1831767,1347480,1739353,1742597,1636006,1728247,1709689,1206645,1383206,1119153,1378317,1527356,1937898,1485322,1404498,1868629,1635265,1860456,1293870,1485349,2031389,1834402,1291372,1838382,1616009,781641,1421830,1763592,1279535,1123468,2024766,975863,1461843,1318585,1137336,1111721,1407705,2349652,1260858,1144070,1219659,1378615,1354139,2015115,1408858,2650864,1810850,1380157,1844909,2055306,1913532,1701963]}]
```

Comment: Paste your json response here.on the basis of the json returned by your query we can parse it in suitable format.

Comment: Hi, Ive added the JSON response. Please let me know if thats what you are looking for. Thanks

Comment: In hardcoded example you can observe that each point contains three values, in your only one, so you need to fix that.